Decode JWE token with AWS KMS service c#
Has anyone used AWS KMS async keys (public/private) to encrypt a payload using the public key without using the KMS service and decrypt the payload using KMS service? The scenario would be I give the public key to a client so they can generate a JWE and we can decrypt it using KMS. My understanding is that KMS private key can't be downloaded so the decryption has to be done within KMS service. I’ve tried the most basic scenario and it throws exception InvalidCiphertextException. It feels like the KMS service can't decrypt a payload that has not been encrypted using the KMS service.
I'm using .net 8 and awssdk.keymanagementservice.3.7.304.
The question is, is it possible to decrypt payloads with kms service that has been generated outside kms service with the public key?
var pkey = await \_kmsClient.GetPublicKeyAsync(new GetPublicKeyRequest { KeyId = \_keyId});


using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(pkey.PublicKey.ToArray(), out _);
    rsa.ExportParameters(false);
    encryptedCek = rsa.Encrypt(cek, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
}

var dec = await _kmsClient.DecryptAsync(new DecryptRequest
{
    CiphertextBlob = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedCek))),
    KeyId = _keyId,
    EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithmSpec.RSAES_OAEP_SHA_256
});

Expecting the payload to be decrypted, but exception InvalidCiphertextException is raised by kms service skd. I tried also without converting to base64 with the same result.
